# How to add new fields by creating unique ID and append it in older DB in postGis?

Tags: postgresql, foreign-keys, unique-index

I am having an DB in POSTGIS which is having following fields like Country,State,District,taluk . Each fields are interlinked with one other by means of ID . Now I want to add new fields (say: Sub_locality & Locality) by creating unique ID and Append it in the old DB How can I do in PostGIS ?any Suggestions? Thanks in advance.

Comment: This is a PostgreSQL question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a pretty conceptual question so I don't know that code can be given in the answer.  But basically you have a number of steps:

1. create your new tables and populate them.
2. add the additional fields (allow nulls at first until you get your db null-free)
3. Populate the additional fields (`update foo set bar_id = (select id from bar where ....)`)

Check for nulls.  Then once you are done, alter the tables to have not null constraints.  If you need an interrim check you can add a `CHECK` constraint that id is below a certain point or the foreign key is not null.